# Check stored procedure exists or not before creating it in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Requirement : Maven profile should be given a directory path, after running my maven profile all the sql files(stored procedures) in that directory should be created in my database.

Note: There is a chance of increasing in sql files in the directory, so if a new file is added, i should only run that file, instead of running all the files.

Problem: Unable to check if the procedure exists or not using IF NOT EXISTS, it is giving me syntax error when i added it in my sql file, before creating my stored procedure.

I tried using

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT  * FROM mysql.proc WHERE name='procedure_1001') THEN
    BEGIN
        CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `procedure_1001`()
        BEGIN
        // logic
        END
    END
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the `ROUTINES` table, like this:

```
SELECT count(*) > 0
into @myvar 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE 
       ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE' 
   AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA='dbname'
   AND ROUTINE_NAME = 'procedure_1001'
;
```

And then use `@myvar` later. If it is 1, then run the procedure.